# Showing message from php action script in form

Tags: php, javascript

How do I show a message from the php action script of a form?

The form is a user login with these fields.

```
<div id="register_user_box" class="inline_form" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; <br/>
     <span id="user_msg"></span><br/>
     <form action="register_user.php" method="post"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="add" /> 
     <input type="hidden" name="edit_user" id="edit_user" value="y" />
     <table cellspacing="0px"> <tr><td>Username:</td></tr><tr><td>
     <input type="text" name="uname" size="30" value="" class="inline_input"/></td> </tr> <tr><td>Email:</td></tr><tr><td>
     <input type="text" name="uemail" size="30" value="" class="inline_input"/></td> </tr> <tr><td>Password:</td></tr><tr><td>
     <input type="password" name="upass" size="30" class="inline_input"/></td> </tr> <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td></tr><tr> <td> 
     <input type="password" name="cpass" size="30" class="inline_input"/></td></tr> </table></td></tr> </table> <p>
     <input class="button" type="submit" name="register" value="Register" style="float:right;"/></p>     
     </form>
</div>
```

The php script register_user.php checks the if the passwords match and shows an error message if they don't.  The script checks all the other fields and prints a message if necessary.

```
<?php

    $messages = array( 'usr_cred_req' => 'Must specify username, email, password.',
                        'usr_name_bad' => 'Bad username selection.  Select a different usrename.', 
                        'usr_name_exists' => 'Username selected already exists.  Select a different username.',
                        'usr_email_bad' => 'Bad email selection.  Select a different email.',
                        'usr_email_exists' => 'Email selected already exists.  Select a different email.',
                        'usr_pass_notmached' => 'Passwords do not match.  Type passwords again.', 
                        'usr_not_added' => 'User not added.',
                        'usr_not_updated' => 'User not updated.',
                        'usr_added' => 'User added.'
                        );

    $username = trim($_REQUEST['uname']);
    $email = trim($_REQUEST['uemail']);
    $password = md5(trim($_REQUEST['upass']));
    $copasswd = md5(trim($_REQUEST['cpass']));


    if ( $password != $copasswd ) { echo '<script> $("#usr_msg").html("'.$messages['usr_pass_notmached'].'"); </script>'; return;}
?>
```

The error message isn't shown and the browser leaves the page.  I'd like the browser to stay on the page and add the error message to the span user_msg.

Comment: doesn't solve the problem but you need to escape the `'` in the `$message` call: `$messages[\'usr_pass_notmached\']`

Comment: As you have it written right now, you just have PHP echoing a `script` into a `span`.  Technically that's what it is doing, even with the improper redirect.  There is actually nothing that _triggers_ the script though.  You need an event, like `onClick` or `onChange` in order for the JS function to work.  But I think for the initial stages of this script, you should remove your JS and follow my suggestions in the answer I gave.

Comment: I just noticed too that you are using `$_REQUEST` when it should be `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the browser to leave the page when the form is submitted, then you will have to use AJAX to submit the form in the background to communicate with the server and then update the container with the error message (or something different on success).

Alternatively, have the PHP form post to itself, check the error messages before you output your HTML and if there was an error, insert the error message in the form markup in the desired location and re-populate the form with all of the values that were originally submitted.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Here's a good jQuery AJAX form plugin. This will prevent page refresh upon submission.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you echoing a JS script to display the error message?  The way you have it written out it won't display a little popup, you just having it filling the `span`.  A better way to do it is something like this:

```
if ( $password != $copasswd ) {
   $display_msg = $messages['usr_pass_notmached']
}
```

Then in your HTML do this:

```
<span><?php echo $display_msg?></span>
```

If the variable is empty then nothing is displayed.  If you do this for all the fields, then you can ensure all the information from the form is returned on error, whether the actual field IS the error or not, preventing the user from having to retype all the information again.  Have the form do a `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to ensure it reloads the same page

I would build the PHP functionality (which can't be turned off by the user) and ensure your form works properly 100% (or close to that) of the time.  Then, once you have that script working, add your JS funcionality to *compliment* your existing code.

What I do in mine, is I build an extra array, in this case `$display_msg` and I run a check of all the input fields.  If a field fails, I add that to the array, `$display_msg['password']` then I move on to the next field.  Once all the fields have been check, I check if the `$display_msg` variable is `empty` or not.  If it's not empty, then I have it fill all the `span` next to the input boxes with red letters explaining the error.  This will print out ALL of the errors at the same time, instead of one at a time while it works it's way down the form.  Next to each input I have a `span` with the given variable name, in this instance `<?php echo $display_msg['password']?>`, then next to the username, `<?php echo $display_msg['username']?>` and so on.  Hope this is clear enough and helps.